# Returning text from article via MediaWiki API?

Tags: javascript, json, mediawiki, mediawiki-api

I'm trying to write a program in JavaScript where the user enters something into a search bar, and the program returns the top 3 Wikipedia results and a short description of each. I can successfully take a search result and return titles with the following syntax:

```
 articles1.append(x.query.search[0].title);
```

However, while the MediaWiki site (https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Parsing_wikitext) leads me to believe that "text" can be used as a parameter similar to "title," the following doesn't return anything:

```
 articles1.append(x.query.search[0].text);
```

The same goes for "summary" or any of the other parameters listed. I feel like I may be fundamentally misunderstanding how these parameters are supposed to work, but since I can at least successfully grab the requested titles, I feel like I can't be too far off. Any help is appreciated, full code is below:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" value='' id=test >
<button>Search</button>

<section class='articles1'>
1.
</section>
<section class='articles2'>
2.
</section>
<section class='articles3'>
3.
</section>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var articles1 = $('.articles1');
    var articles2 = $('.articles2');
    var articles3 = $('.articles3');
    var input = $( 'input' );
    var button = $( 'button' );
    var toSearch = '';
    var searchUrl = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php';

    $("button").click( function(e) {
        var search = document.getElementById("test").value;
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php',
            data: { action: 'query', list: 'search', srsearch: search, format: 'json' },
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function( x ) {
                articles1.append( x.query.search[0].title );
                articles2.append( x.query.search[1].title );
                articles3.append( x.query.search[2].title );
            }
        })
    })
})
```

Comment: In your ajax request's success function, try logging x to the console. That will let you explore the shape of the object, which should tell you exactly what's available and how to access it.

Answer (score 1):

The [Parsing WikiText](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Parsing_wikitext) page you're referring to explains how to parse arbitrary WikiText. It's not relevant here.

You are using the [Search API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Search), and may only use the returned properties of that module. In this instance, you might be looking for the `snippet` property:

```
articles1.append( x.query.search[0].snippet );
```

Look at the [Search API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Search) documentation for more options.

---

P.S. you can also use [MediaWiki's API Sandbox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:ApiSandbox) to play around and test your API requests.